# Rails 4 Friendly Id Slug Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the following:

```
gem 'friendly_id', github: 'FriendlyId/friendly_id', branch: 'master'
```

I am creating an Article section on my Rails 4 website.  The problem I am having is that when I change a existing article's name the slug is not updated.

This is what I have so far:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

add_column :articles, :slug, :string
add_index :articles, :slug, unique: true
```

Comment: Maybe try out this method from friendly_id 4 (-> Rails 3 compat. version) http://rubydoc.info/github/FriendlyId/friendly_id/4.0-stable/file/Guide.rdoc#Deciding_When_to_Generate_New_Slugs

Comment: yeah that worked by just adding: def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    true
  end

Comment: Most helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In FriendlyId 4 (Rails 3 compatible) there was a method

```
should_generate_new_friendly_id?
```

and you could define it on your model to control when slug is regenerated.
Try

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  name_changed?
end
```

to regenerate slug when name changes.

EDIT

FriendlyId version 5 (Rails 4 compatible) doesn't regenerate slugs on save anymore. To restore this functionality you can either set slug column to `nil` before saving or use the solution provided above.

EDIT 2

You need to override the slug setter for your saves to work for Rails <5 & FriendlyId > 5 as referenced in this [issue](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/488).

Add this to the model file

```
  def slug=(value)
    if value.present?
      write_attribute(:slug, value)
    end
  end
```

Comment: was name_changed? an random example? or should we add '_changed?' for the model?

Comment: @HarshaMV `[attribute]_changed?` is a method generated for you by Rails.

Comment: pfff honestly, even setting the slug to nil is not working. Since friendly_id has updated for rails 3, version 5 etc… it just got randomly working. Meaning, *mega-randomly*. Too bad.

Comment: @Ben Can you elaborate? Maybe by asking new SO question, I'm eager to help you resolve it.

Comment: Yup I did explained a little bit more here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533422/rails4-remote-links-and-templates-naming thanks for the help you'd provide

Comment: Best workaround I've found is to manually set the slug to nil, and re-save the model every time you do anything that requires it be updated.  We cannot count on "dirty" (changed?) working (per above), and there is not a way I know of to move the gem's callback later in the callback-cycle (i.e. not in before_validate).

Answer (score 6):

I have this issues and just want to point out what I've noticed.

if you only do as in docs

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

and then run `Post.find_each(&:save)`  - slug is gonna get updated...

However in my case, I also have these in my model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

 def normalize_friendly_id(text)
   text.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
 end

 def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
   title_changed?
 end
end
```

with the code above it won't do anything when you run `Post.find_each(&:save)` I assume since your title doesn't change. (first method handles russian language)

so when working with the first model all worked great, but then when I copied ready code to next model I wanted to slugify, I run into some issues. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is trying to illustrate - it's clear the second code example with the two method definitions is problematic, but in what way was it problematic? How did you resolve the issues? Which version of Friendly_Id and Rails are you running? Thanks :)

Comment: It's been 2 years, but I'll try to answer :). I believe the point was that sometimes you want custom behavior in terms of whether to update title or not. suppose you 
1.  added `should_generate_new_friendly_id?`
2. some time passed and now you want to regenerate slugs again. 
     `Post.find_each(&:save)` - as suggested in docs isn't going to work. 

I guess it was the point.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue where the slug don't want to change on update even though I had the following in my model:

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  slug.blank? || title_changed?
end
```

In my case I wasn't setting the title directly via the form but in a `before_save` callback, and that was the reason, because it seems that FriendlyID needs the change to happen not only before saving but even `before_validation` so I changed my code to:

```
before_validation :set_title

def set_title
  self.title = 'some dynamic way of getting title'
end
```

And, that worked for me!

I really spent too much time trying to figure out why it wasn't working, so I'm posting this case here for anyone who may get stuck in the same situation (and hopefully save you long hours of debugging)