# Friendly_id change slug on Record Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

Am i doing something wrong ? **on Record update, slug is not being updated**.

```
 class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 extend FriendlyId

 friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

 def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
     true
 end
```

I'm using:

```
 friendly_id (5.0.4)
 Rails 4.1.7
 ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630)
```

This is how I'm trying in terminal:

```
  c = Company.last
  c.slug = nil 
  c.name = "testing abb"
  c.save
  c.reload
  c.slug // nil 
  c.name // testing abb
```

at the time of create: it inserts the slug but doesnt update on record update. any idea ?

Comment: hey, did you get things working? cause I see you neither have accepted my answer nor posted your solution

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764359/rails-4-friendly-id-slug-not-updating/17765270

Answer (score 11):

Add `:history` to `friendly_id :name, use: %i(slugged finders)`:

```
friendly_id(:name, use: :i[slugged history finders])
```

and override `should_generate_new_friendly_id` method to meet your needs:

```
 # will change the slug if the name changed
 def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
   name_changed?
 end
```

Comment: I already override the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` as i mentioned above in the code. 

but i figured it out. the problem is that Model.rb file is too large and i didnt notice the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` is already defined in the end of the file by some other developer :)

Comment: There is no such thing, as `model.rb` "didnt notice" something.. Your method is not working, because you don't tell it what changes to track, but simply return `true`. Follow the guidance I've provided and it will work

Comment: Andrey, I believe that kashif simply meant that he/she did not notice that the model class already had this method defined.

Answer (score 0):

As per the below post, slug is not changed in friendly_id 5 and above on record update.

[Rails 4 Friendly Id Slug Not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764359/rails-4-friendly-id-slug-not-updating/17765270)